# How to save Ycbcr numpy array to an image without changing its array points?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, ycbcr

I had an rgb image which I converted into Ycbcr array.

```
rgb = cv2.imread(image)
r,g,b = cv2.split(rgb)

def ycbcr(r, g, b): 
     y = .299*r + .587*g + .114*b
     cb = 128 -.168736*r -.331364*g + .5*b
     cr = 128 +.5*r - .418688*g - .081312*b
     x= cv2.merge((y,cb,cr))
  return x
```

`plt.savefig("Ycbcr_new.jpg")` # saved in a new folder on my desktop

I saved this array as Ycbcr_new.jpg, Now I converted this new Ycbcr_new image into an array.

```
ycbcr1 = cv2.imread(Ycbcr_new.jpg)
ycbcr1 == x
```

The answer is:  "False"

My question is Is it possible to save the new YCbCr array into a YCbCr image on my desktop without changing its array points?

Thank you

Comment: JPEG is lossy. Saving and then re-reading the same image will result in your data changing. Use PNG if you want lossless.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried but it wasn't working. :(